# optimal model for specific dataset

Tags: deep-learning, classification, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets, conv-neural-network

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFURD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L23VY.png)

Hello genius programmers. my major is architecture engineering and in this semester project I'm doing project using deeplearning. at first, I was going to classify those not-complete structure that has missing member like safety railing and safety plate of portable scaffolding. But, the problem is there are many different models so I'm worried that feature extraction won't be proceeded well. because in general image classification,differences of different classes are clear. But, in my data, there are difference of missing member but, also of between different model(although their lable is same in Complete-structure.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2pCt.png)

1. so, what kind of model is optimal for that data classification?
2. and I'm going to label like this, Complete-scaffolding and not-complete-scaffolding. not-complete-scaffolding is augmentated from complete scaffolding but not from train-complete-scaffolding data. do this work for high accuracy?
3. if general CNN is not appropriate, how about RCNN or fine-grained classification?

thank you for reading my not organized question and this is my first ask in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

*Optimal* is rather hard goal to reach. If you want the optimal results then you would need to create many different models and test each one to determine the best. Additionally, you would also want to fine-tune the different hyperparameters in each model.

However, if you are willing to settle for good but not perfect results, then I would recommend a fairly deep CNN model paired with lots of good training data.